# How tasty would it be?

Tags: conditionals, would

As a student of English, I have met two possible types of uses of the word "would". The first type of use refers to a situation that can actually happen, while the second one refers to a situation that cannot happen.

**first type of use example**
I would be happy to help you.

**second type of use example**
If I had wings, I would fly to XYZ place.

In the following sentence, does the word "would" refer to the first or second type of use?

sentence: **How tasty would it be?**

EDIT: context: modifying a recipe and discussing possible changes in food taste after the modification

Thank you.

Comment: Hi Peter. Welcome. I’d suggest you not think of your type-2 usages as impossible, but merely contrary to the present state of affairs. “If I were President of the US, I’d focus more on science policy.” Many people **could** become President, but they certainly aren’t at present; only one at a time.

Comment: Both examples refer to what would be the case IF some element were different or available. Think of the first as follows.  *If you allow me to do so, **I would be happy to help you***.

Answer (score 1):

You are not correct to assume that the second type could not happen. It means the opposite: conditional on the first assertion, it *would* and therefore could happen. It's just that the first assertion couldn't happen. It's not that the word "would" means that anything is impossible.

That being said, given your context of modifying a recipe, you could rephrase it as "If the recipe was modified, how tasty would it be?"

This aligns with the second sense (conditional on modification, would it be tasty?). However, "would" is not used to indicate something is impossible, so of course it is still possible for the recipe to be tasty.