# How tasty would it be?

Tags: would

As a student of English, I have met two possible types of uses of the word "would". The first type of use refers to a situation that can actually happen, while the second one refers to a situation that cannot happen.

First type of use example

> I would be happy to help you.

Second type of use example

> If I had wings, I would fly to XYZ place.

In the following sentence, does the word "would" refer to the first or second type of use?

> **How tasty would it be?**

**EDIT: context: modifying a recipe and discussing possible changes in food taste after the modification**

Comment: What is 'it' in this case?

Comment: ..lets say food

Comment: The first example *(I would be happy to help you)* just uses "hesitant, deferential" ***would be*** instead of ***will be*** (or more straightforwardly, ***am***), so it's not actually a true "conditional" usage at all. Your "tasty" example ***is*** conditional *(**If** this recipe change **were to be made**, how **would** that affect the taste?)*, so it's the same as ***if** I had wings I **would** be able to fly*.

Comment: 'If snakes had wings, would they fly over seas?' uses an impossible protasis. 'If we added more cumin and substituted beans for sweetcorn' uses a hypothetical but feasible protasis. That is where the difference really lies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How tasty would it be?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/340746/how-tasty-would-it-be)